# Getting value of a form doesn't work

Tags: javascript

My task is checking what an user keys in. If he keys in "Mars", he gets the value.

```
PLanet: <input type="text"  id="form_1">
<input type="submit" onClick="send()" value="Send">
<script> 
var planetEntered = document.getElementById('form_1').value;

var plantesLength = new Array(3);
plantesLength['Mars'] = 52; 
plantesLength['Venera'] = 30;
plantesLength['Earth'] = 10;
plantesLength['Merkyriy'] = 60;
alert(plantesLength['Merkyriy']);
function send() {
switch(form_1) {
    case 'Mars': 
    alert(plantesLength['Mars']);
    break;

    case 'Venera': 
    alert(plantesLength['Venera']);
    break;

    case 'Earth':
    alert(plantesLength['Earth']);
    break;

    case 'Merkyriy': 
    alert(plantesLength['Merkyriy']);
    break;

    default: 
    alert("К сожалению, мы не нашли ни одну программу.");
    break;
}
   }
```

The function returns default-block. How to fix? Thanks.

Comment: Where is `form_1` getting initialized?

Comment: Look at the first line of the code.

Comment: You can't set value in `switch` like this! you should use `switch(planetEntered)`

Comment: What do you mean? Apparently, you meant that I can't set such argument into switch? Do you mean that I can't do so: switch(form_1)?

Comment: You can't do `switch(form_1)` as there is no such a variable named `form_1` exists! Do `switch(planetEntered)`!

Comment: I've done it but is is still not working. It returns default-block.

Comment: See my answer with explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

you have to get the input values inside the `send` function.

Demo Link http://jsbin.com/ejaSUTiH/1/

```
    PLanet: <input type="text"  id="form_1">
    <input type="submit" onClick="send()" value="Send">


<script> 
    var plantesLength = new Array(3);
    plantesLength['Mars'] = 52; 
    plantesLength['Venera'] = 30;
    plantesLength['Earth'] = 10;
    plantesLength['Merkyriy'] = 60;
    alert(plantesLength['Merkyriy']);
    function send() {
      var planetEntered = document.getElementById('form_1').value;
      console.log(planetEntered);
    switch(planetEntered) {
        case 'Mars': 
        alert(plantesLength['Mars']);
        break;

        case 'Venera': 
        alert(plantesLength['Venera']);
        break;

        case 'Earth':
        alert(plantesLength['Earth']);
        break;

        case 'Merkyriy': 
        alert(plantesLength['Merkyriy']);
        break;

        default: 
        alert("К сожалению, мы не нашли ни одну программу.");
        break;
    }
       }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to declare a variable inside the function send(): And set 
`planetEntered` in switch case for checking:

```
function send() {
    var planetEntered = document.getElementById('form_1').value; // Here
    switch(planetEntered) { // Change

    }
}
```

[**<kbd>JS Fiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/DT8e9/)

Comment: I've understood what you've meant. I've already solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign the value of the input box in the send() method so it's value is the default (empty) when send() is called.